# Delete rows based on range of values in column

Tags: r, rows, subset

I would like to delete rows of data in a *dataframe* if the values in a column (in this case a participant identification number) fall within a certain range e.g. 61701 to 61721 & 61901 to 61929.

I know how to subset data based on a threshold e.g.:

```
datasetnew = dataset[dataset$X<=100, ]
```

But not sure how to subset and remove the rows using a range of numbers. Not sure subset is what I need.

Comment: Haven't tested, but probably something simple like `dataset[(dataset$X >= 61701 & dataset$X <= 61721) | (dataset$X >= 61901 & dataset$X <= 61929),]` or `dataset[dataset$X %in% 61701:61721) | (dataset$X %in% 61901:61929),]`. Probably could use `with` too in order to reduce `dataset` calls

Comment: Thanks David this works perfectly for subsetting the data. What I want to do is remove those particular rows from the dataframe. I should have thought it through more!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or a more straight forward implementation will be just negate these rows using `!`

```
dataset[with(dataset, !((X >= 61701 & X <= 61721) | (X >= 61901 & X <= 61929))), ]
```

Or

```
dataset[with(dataset, !((X %in% 61701:61721) | (X %in% 61901:61929))), ]
```

For a big data set you can use `data.table`s `%between%` function

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataset)[!(X %between% c(61701, 61721) | X %between% c(61901, 61929))]
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to exclude those ranges by including everything less than, greater than, and in between them. Something like:

```
dataset[dataset$X < 61701 | dataset$X > 61929 | (dataset$X > 61721 & dataset$X < 61901),]
```

Or using `subset`:

```
subset(dataset, X < 61701 | X > 61929 | (X > 61721 & X < 61901)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) package:

```
exclude <- c(61701:61721, 61901:61929)

library(dplyr)
datasetnew <- dataset %>%
  filter(!(X %in% exclude))
```